# Angular components with javascript models and ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to create an angular component, a timepicker, using plain javascript models, I want the controller of the component expose an api and also working with ngModel.
I'm pretty newbie with angular and don't know how to work with ngModel. I have two inputs inside the template with hours and minutes. My problem  is that I don't know how to pass the ngmodel parameters to the controller.

I've prepared a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aal3VP?p=preview

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  function DemoController() {
    this.tpVal = {
      hours: 10,
      minutes: 0
    };
  }
  app.controller('DemoController', DemoController);

  function TimePickerModel(config) {

    this.show = config.show || true;

    this.hours = null;

    this.minutes = null;

  }

  function TimePickerController() {

    // API for state
    this.model = new TimePickerModel({});
  }

  TimePickerController.prototype.show = function showTimePicker() {
    this.model.show = true;
  };

  TimePickerController.prototype.hide = function hideTimePicker() {
    this.model.show = false;
  };

  TimePickerController.prototype.setHours = function setHoursTimePicker(hours) {
    this.model.hours = hours;
  };

  TimePickerController.prototype.setMinutes = function setMinutesTimePicker(minutes) {
    this.model.minutes = minutes;
  };

  TimePickerController.prototype.setValue = function setValueTimePicker(value) {
    this.model.hours = value;
    this.model.minutes = value;
  };

  app.directive('timepicker', function($compile) {

    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      controller: 'TimePickerController',
      scope: {},
      require: 'ngModel',
      templateUrl: 'timepicker.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        //console.log('Model val: ' + ngModel.$modelValue);
        //console.log('View val: ' + ngModel.$viewValue);
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          //Do something with your model
          console.log(scope.model);
          var actualValue = ngModel.$modelValue;
          console.log('Model val: ' + ngModel.$modelValue.hours);
          console.log('View val: ' + ngModel.$viewValue.hours);
          //console.log(element.find('input')[0]);
          //element.find('input')[0].val(actualValue.hours);
        }
      }
    };
  });

  app.controller('TimePickerController', TimePickerController);

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="DemoController as ctrl">
      {{ctrl.tpVal}}
      <timepicker ng-model="ctrl.tpVal"></timepicker>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` is a [standard angular directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bound inputs values to scope property, you don't need to inject it or call the directive property with the same name. If you want to inject the values from the controller into the directive, you can use scope property for that.
in directive:

```
scope: {
        model : '=time'
      },
```

in index.html

```
   <timepicker time="ctrl.tpVal"></timepicker>
```

Check that modification: http://plnkr.co/edit/cJ0mjI?p=preview. 
You also can see how changing model value inside the directive can propargate outside by adding dummy `increaseHours` function in directive;

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to keep the state, it's not possible to do it using the ng-model?

Comment: can you explain what d mean 'to keep the state' ? keep the naming or have separated what you increment in the directing and in controller?

Comment: Sorry, I'm explaining really bad. I mean, for example, from the DemoController call ctrl.tpVal.$dirty to know if the user has already interacted.

Comment: Can you explain withouth involving angular specific terms - what you want to achieve? That's the simplest way to formulate a task , then we'll see what on your code is missing to accomplish it

Comment: The developer who uses the directive might be able to add client validations and server validations, also know if the value has been changed by the user or not, etc.